# How to scroll window without overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to scroll in a window but my window height is too small to scroll. Is it possible to scroll when the height of container is too small to see the scrollbar. 
Here is my code to scroll:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+1);
  $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-1);
}, 800);
```

I need to scroll window or body even if height of it is less than 100px.

Comment: Scroll it to where? It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you are talking about triggering scroll event that you simply need to use  $(window).scroll(); http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_scroll.asp

Comment: scroll to where ? and how ? could you share your html so that we can replicate

Answer (score 3):

I *believe* you want to set a `min-height` of `110%` on `html` in your CSS. I would do:

```
html {
  min-height: 110%;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/sebago/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

To see scrollbar, just use CSS property `overflow:scroll;` on your container.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a fixed height in your element, then you can use overflow:scroll to enable scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You need first hide the scroll bar to do not take space (because you don't have too much space in the element), you can make that with the next css:

```
#elementId{ 
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then you need to bind the mousewheel event over the 'small' element and trigger a function to manually scroll your element, you can do that with the next jQuery code:

```
$('#elementId').bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e) {
    $('#elementId').scrollTop($('#elementId').scrollTop()+1);
});
```

This example is simplified just to bind the mousewheel event in general, to know if it is up or down you can use the **jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin** that you can get [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel).

Comment: 'DOMMouseScroll' binding is for Firefox browsers